# inconsistent font sizes used for subsubsection/paragraph titles in tex4ht. How to fix?

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, tex4ht

I noticed in tex4ht that the size of the font used for the paragraph title is the same as that of the section title (i.e. too large) and the size of the font for the subsubsection is smaller than that used for the paragraph, which it should be larger or at least the same size.

This makes looking at titles confusing as font size gives indication of order.

The font size should decrease all the way from chapter to paragraph. Now it decreases but then starts to increase once it reaches paragraph.

in PDF, it is consistent, as the sizes decrease correctly from chapter to paragraph. Screen shots below

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}
\title{my book title}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\part{first part}
\chapter{first chapter}
\section{first section}
\subsection{first subsection}
\subsubsection{first subsubsection}
\paragraph{first paragraph}

\end{document}
```

Compiled using

```
make4ht -ulm default -a debug  foo.tex 'mathjax,htm'
```

Gives

[image]

Compared to the pdf where the sizes decreases uniformly (but hard to see if font used for paragraph is smaller or same as subsubsection, but at least it is not larger like with the HTML)

[image]

**Question is**: How to make the size of the font used for paragraph title with tex4ht not be larger than subsubsection? Is there a way to control these settings?

TL 2022

[Link to ticket](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?592)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX4ht in fact doesn't assign any font sizes for sections at all. So it seems that the default style used by browser causes sectioning level `<h5>`, produced by the `\subsubsection` command, to be smaller than the normal text. `\paragraph` produces title which is of the same size as the surrounding text, only in bold. As the text of paragraph immediately follows the title, you cannot use HTML sectioning elements for that.

You can easily change that using CSS:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{.partHead { font-size: 2em; }}
\Css{.chapterHead { font-size: 1.7411em; }}
\Css{.sectionHead { font-size: 1.5157em; }}
\Css{.subsectionHead { font-size: 1.3195em; }}
\Css{.subsubsectionHead { font-size: 1.1487em; }}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The generated html for the titles looks like this (slightly cleaned):

```html
<h1 class='partHead' id='first-part'><span class='titlemark'>Part I<br /></span><a id='x1-1000I'></a>first part</h1>  
<h2 class='chapterHead' id='first-chapter'><span class='titlemark'>Chapter 1</span><br /><a id='x1-20001'></a>first chapter</h2>
<h3 class='sectionHead' id='first-section'><span class='titlemark'>1.1   </span> <a id='x1-30001.1'></a>first section</h3>
<h4 class='subsectionHead' id='first-subsection'><span class='titlemark'>1.1.1   </span> <a id='x1-40001.1.1'></a>first subsection</h4>
<h5 class='subsubsectionHead' id='first-subsubsection'><span class='titlemark'>1.1.1.1   </span> <a id='x1-50001.1.1.1'></a>first subsubsection</h5>
<span class='paragraphHead' id='first-paragraph'><a id='x1-60001.1.1.1.1'></a><span class='ec-lmbx-10'>first paragraph</span></span>
```

So the section levels are displayed with headers `h1` to `h5` but a paragraph is not displayed with `h6` (which is the deepest header level in html) but as normal text. This is bigger than `h5`, which is normally 0.83 times the size of normal text (see http://zuga.net/articles/html-heading-elements/ for example).

However, there is a `class` defined for the paragraph header called `paragraphHead`. So you can add some custom css for this in a tex4ht configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{.paragraphHead{font-size:0.83em;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Save this file as `htparagraph.cfg` for example and compile as follows:

```
make4ht -c htparagraph.cfg -ulm default -a debug foo.tex 'mathjax,htm'
```

Result:

[image]

Note that in my output for some reason the `secnumdepth` is not taken into account, but I guess that is not the main issue here.

It would be better to configure `\paragraph` to use `h5` as well, but this may be an easy workaround.

Comment: I recently fixed the numbering issue with `\paragraph`, I think. It should be fixed in up-to-date TeX Live.